# Rstudio does not stop at breakpoint

Tags: r, for-loop, debugging, rstudio, breakpoints

A few weeks ago I worked with breakpoints in Rstudio. It worked as I expected: stopping at breakpoints.

However, now I need to use it again, I can't get it to work; more specifically: when I set a breakpoint in Rstudio a red dot is appearing next to the code line (see screenshot), but when running the code, it does not stop at the break point.

I created a simple code example for this post to show what I want: run a for loop line for line.[image: screenshot Rstudio]

Perhaps I am just not understanding something :) So, could anyone help me with getting these usefull debugging tools in Rstudio to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running the code exactly? Are you sourcing the file?

Comment: I used "run" to run through the for loop. But now I tried "source"  and, indeed, the debugging functionality works :) I wasn't so aware of these two options to run code. Any easy explanation on the difference? In any way: thanks for your help!

Comment: Choosing "run" is just like copying and pasting code into the console. You kind of loose track of line numbers and breakpoints that way. You need to source code as a file in order to for the debugger to able to place breakpoints in the code. It's really just a side effect of R being a mostly interpreted language.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I'm getting the same error -- when I run a Shiny App, the breakpoint is not hit, but when I source the helper file directly, then the breakpoint IS hit.

Comment: What exactly should I do step by step to stop the code at a breakpoint?

Answer (score 5):

Breakpoints also do not work for me on shiny app developed in RStudio, I am using `browser()` instead of breakpoints, and it works.

[see this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio)

M